# c++ - why the result is minus?

Tags: c++, octal

I have some problem with my simple program where if my input more than 295600127, the result is minus (-).

here :

```
#‎include‬ <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int konarray(int b);
void konbil(int A[], int &n);
int kali(int x);
main(){
   int b;
   char *awal,akhir,pil;
   awal:
   system("COLOR 9F");
   cout<<"enter decimal\t= ";cin>>b;
   //calling function of conversion to an array of integers
   konarray(b);
   akhir:
   cout<<"\n\nDo You Want To Reply Now ? (Y/N) : ";
   cin >> pil;
   cout<<endl;
   switch(pil){
      case 'Y' :
      case 'y' :
         system ("cls");
         goto awal;
          break;
      case'N':
      case 'n' :
          break;
      default:
      system("COLOR c0");
      system ("cls");
      cout << "Please, make sure for entering the choise!!\n\n\n\n";
      goto akhir;
   }
}
//convertion numer to array
int konarray(int b){
   int A[30];
   int i,n,h,s;
   i=0;
   do{
      h=b/8;
      s=b%8;
      b=h;
      A[i]=s;
      i++;
   }
   while(h!=0);
   n=i;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      cout<<A[i]<<" ";
   konbil(A,n);
}
//array to octal
void konbil(int A[],int &n){
   int c,i;
   c=A[0];
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
      c=c+A[i]*kali(i);
   system("COLOR f0");
   cout<<endl<<"the results of the conversion are\t= ";
   cout<<c<<endl;
}
int kali(int x){
   if (x==1)
      return (10);
   else
      return(10*kali(x-1));
}
```

i have tried change of all int into long, but it was same.

I want to know some reason why?

and how to fix it?

Comment: I which way is your code posted a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the problem you're actually asking about?

Comment: oh, sorry, i think this is simple program that can be try.

Comment: I would leave out all of that unnecessary input code, and assign the values directly, to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: At least on 32-bit Linux, an `int` and `long` is basically the same. To get the max value, you can `#include <climits>` and then print `INT_MAX` and `LONG_MAX`. Other constants available can be checked from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
long long int
```

This program

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(long int) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(long long int) << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

gives

```
4
4
8
```

showing you need long long int to get 64 bits

Change like this:

```
void konbil(int A[],int &n){
   unsigned long long c,i;     // unsigned long long 
   c=A[0];
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
      c=c+A[i]*kali(i);
   system("COLOR f0");
   cout<<endl<<"the results of the conversion are\t= ";
   cout<<c<<endl;
}
```

The largest positive number you can store int an int is 2147483647 (2^31 - 1).
Adding just 1 to that number will result in the value -2147483648 (- 2^31).

So the answer is that you have an overflow while using int.
Therefore you need long long int or even better unsigned long long.

unsigned long long can't be negative and allows the maximum value (2^64 - 1).

EDIT:
An extra question was added in the comment - therefore this edit.

**int**

On most systems an int is 32 bits.

It can take values from -2^31 to 2^31-1, i.e. from -2147483648 to 2147483647

**unsigned int**

An unsigned int is also 32 bits. However an unsigned int can not be negative.

Instead it has the range 0 to 2^32-1, i.e. from 0 to 4294967295

**long long int**

When you use long long int you have 64 bits.

So the valid range is -2^63 to 2^63-1, i.e. -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

**unsigned long long**

A unsigned long long is also 64 bits but can not be negative.

The range is 0 to 2^64-1, i.e. 0 to 18446744073709551615

Try this code:

```
int main()
{
    cout << endl << "Testing int:" << endl;

    int x = 2147483647;   // max positive value
    cout << x << endl;

    x = x + 1;            // OVERFLOW
    cout << x << endl;

    cout << endl << "Testing unsigned int:" << endl;

    unsigned int y = 4294967295;   // max positive value
    cout << y << endl;

    y = y + 1;            // OVERFLOW
    cout << y << endl;

    cout << endl << "Testing long long int:" << endl;

    long long int xl = 9223372036854775807LL;   // max positive value
    cout << xl << endl;

    xl = xl + 1;            // OVERFLOW
    cout << xl << endl;

    cout << endl << "Testing unsigned long long:" << endl;

    unsigned long long yl = 18446744073709551615ULL;   // max positive value
    cout << yl << endl;

    yl = yl + 1;            // OVERFLOW
    cout << yl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

it will give you

```
Testing int:
2147483647
-2147483648

Testing unsigned int:
4294967295
0

Testing long long int:
9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808

Testing unsigned long long:
18446744073709551615
0
```

showing how you overflow from max positive value by adding just 1.

Also see this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Comment: What about this question he asked - "I want to know some reason why?"

Comment: @nielsen : taht was same, the result is -181203535

Comment: @newbie - I'll add an explanation to the answer

Answer (score 3):

295600128 decimal is octal is 2147500000. When you try to then put 2147500000 as a decimal number into an `int`, it overflows the 4 byte signed limit, which gives you the negative value.

One question - why do you want to store an octal number back in a variable as a decimal number? If you just want to display the number, you already have it in `A`.

If you just want to display a number as octal, std::ostream can already do this:

```
std::cout << std::oct << b << '\n';
```

If for some reason you really do need a decimal representation of an octal number in an integer variable, you will need to change `c` and `kali` to long long.